# Cannot parse netsh output with a for/f loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

The `netsh` command outputs this :

```cmd
C:\> netsh int ip sh route store=persistent | findstr -v 0.0.0.0/0 | more +3
Oui      Autre     1    192.168.10.128/26           0  192.168.10.1
```

I'm trying to fetch the 4th column in the output of the `netsh` with a `for/f` loop :

```cmd
C:> for /f "skip=3 tokens=4" %f in ('netsh int ip sh route store=persistent ^| findstr -v 0.0.0.0/0') do @echo %f

C:>
```

But this works :

```cmd
C:> for /f "tokens=4" %f in ("col1 col2 col3 col4") do @echo %f
col4
```

EDIT0 : This documentation can help : https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Can you help me ?

Comment: What happens if you escape the `=` character with another caret?

Comment: @Compo Your suggestion works, thanks a lot :). Can you please convert your comment to an answer and explain why I needed to also escape the `=` character ?

Comment: Whilst I'm glad that you've got it sorted, I'm not going to add my comment as an answer, because your question should be closed due to the fix simply being a missed escape character. It will be of no use to future readers, who are unlikely to have made exactly the same mistake with the same command within a for loop. The command within the `for` parentheses is passed to `cmd` as arguments, and `cmd` sees the `=` character as a standard delimiter, _(like with the space and comma characters, for instance)_.

Comment: @Compo One should at least give some documentation about those delimiters because as far as I'm concerned only the `|` needed to be escaped. Neither `for/?` nor `cmd/?` mention that `=` is a delimiter that need to be escaped in `for/f` loops. Moreover, I don't see why you need to close this question as the future readers need to know WHY the `=` needs to be escaped.

Comment: SebMa. I've explained to you that is it a standard delimiter. If you want to find out what cmd.exe sees as delimiters, look it up yourself, there's certainly no obligation on myself to do that for you too. And to be honest, after I've helped you to fix your issue already, I think it rude that you expect more from me, _and not the rest of the community, who have so far, not helped you at all with your issue!_ Create a batch file containing just `@Echo [%1] [%2] [%3] [%4] [%5]` for instance, then call it with some test strings, e.g. `call mybat.cmd one,two=three;four five`, and see what happens.

Comment: @Compo I didn't say "YOU should" but One. By that I meant anyone. Moreover I should have written "could" instead of "should", that was a typo. I'm sorry I hurt your feelings I never meant to be rude. God bless for your help.

Comment: Regardless; you seem to be suggesting that your question should remain open in order for anyONE to post links to the documentation on what cmd.exe sees as delimiters. I do not think answers should provide links to documentation like that, there are many good search engines, all capable of finding it directly.

Comment: @Compo Not exactly because some information is hard to find given one does not have the right keywords especially when English is not their born/natural language (I'm French, BTW). That is why I'm asking you to please leave this question open.